# Duplicate Nuxt Path - Heroku

Tags: heroku, nuxtjs3

All css and image links are with a `_nuxt` aditional in their path like `/_nuxt/_nuxt/home1.5334375a.webp`

Here is my last modifications to `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/google-fonts"],
  modules: ["nuxt-windicss", "@vueuse/nuxt", "@pinia/nuxt"],
  css: ["assets/styles/custom.css"],
  runtimeConfig: {
    apiSecret: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
    public: {
      BASE_URL: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/persistedState.ts", ssr: false, mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/maska.ts", ssr: false, mode: "client" },
  ],
  alias: {
    assets: "/assets",
    '@vue/devtools-api': '@vue/devtools-api',
  }
});
```

Updating:

I changed the dependencies and the problem gone away:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/kit": "3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "c8": "^7.11.0",
    "maska": "^1.5.0",
    "swiper": "^8.3.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "vitest": "^0.16.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "boxicons": "^2.1.2"
  }
```

I removed Vite dependecies

Comment: How do you write that in code? The result + TS config will not help us here.

Comment: Was talking more about the actual template with the image etc.